# Commit/Rollback transaction not listed in MON$TRANSACTIONS

Tags: transactions, firebird, firebird-3.0

We have a strange issue in a customer's Firebird database. We noticed an active transaction not listed in the `mon$transactions` table.

According to the gstat utility, transaction 231.768.260 is active:
[image]

However, running a simple `SELECT * FROM mon$transactions where mon$transaction_id = 231768260` does not return such transaction ID.

I thought it could be in limbo, so I decided run gfix with limbo switch, and the results are no transactions in limbo:

[image]

I tried to manually rollback it:

[image]

And it warned me that transaction is active.

Is there some way to correct this situation? Right now, the only thing I can think of is to do a backup/restore - creating a fresh new DB and discard this one.

To be honest this kind issue is rare but frustrating.

Any tip will be appreciate.

Comment: Backup and restore shouldn't be necessary. A shutdown and online of the database with gfix should be enough, or a restart of the Firebird process. AFAIK, Firebird should then detect that the transaction is not active anymore and handle it appropriately (see https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/how_to/doc_400 under "Bitmap with Transaction States").

Comment: whom do you run that query by?  `SELECT CURRENT_USER, t.* FROM mon$transactions t` ?

Comment: i wonder how would *autonomous transacitons* and *remote transactions* be displayed, especially on a classic server. BTW, is your FB3 configured as classic or as super ?

Comment: My configuration is Classic Server. And aswering your first question, the user is SYSDBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark pointed, a reboot of Firebird service removed the problematic transaction.

After that I noticed two things:

1. first connection to the server was very slow - I think FB was garbage collecting.
2. some minutes later after first connection, queries were slower than they used to be.

Anyway, I decided to do a backup/restore and everything is fine.

Comment: The second part of your answer doesn't seem to belong in an answer. I would recommend editing your answer to make it more focused on the solution, and maybe create a new question here, on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support) about that. Slow downs are usually caused by increasing gaps in oldest interesting and oldest active transactions, so make sure to include the gstat -h output of your database when asking such a question.

Comment: Good point. I'll create a new question. But the gap between OIT/OAT and "Next Transaction" is low, sometimes just one.

Comment: `queries were slower than they used to be.` - i suspect that was rebuilding index trees after mass deletion of obsolete records